# Rendering into an ember view's outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a view:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'parent',
  mouseEnter: function() {
    // Do something
  }
});
```

whose template has an `{{outlet}}`.

Here's the JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2779/edit

I'm trying to render into the outlet, and I can't figure out why it's not working. I tried putting the `render` call in an `Em.run.next`, because this issue is similar to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3626

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, but this isn't supported, here's some reasons:

1. The documentation specifies that the into is the route (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/).
2. It's a dynamic view, which makes it an interesting problem, if you have multiple instances of the view, which would ember choose?

That being said you can still restructure the app to handle what you want

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2785/edit